# Есть виджеты реализованные для QT?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужен виджет секундомера, градусника, компаса и шкалы топлива.В одном стиле. Есть отдельная библиотека, модуль где это реализовано на c++ для qt? Кроме qwt еще есть вариант ?

Comment: таких модулей в библиотеке не может быть. Библиотека выдает только инструменты... Это не ответ, а только мое мнение